# Facebook vs GDPR - Is Facebook never deleting the Searches you do?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, european-union, data-protection, database

I frequently delete the Search History from my account's Activity Log.

However, every time I start typing in Search, Facebook seems to remember perfectly searches I've done in the past.

Suggestions include names with and without diacritics (e.g. with "a" or with "á"), names of people who are not in my friends list (nor added me) and I have never chatted with them, names of pages I never 'Liked', etc...
It's definitely from past searches, and not suggestions based on close friends, chats or anything.

Is Facebook holding this information forever and **are they allowed to do that**?

[image: Activity Log empty]

[image: Suggestions include past searches]

I use Chrome. I've just opened Opera with VPN enabled, log into Facebook with my account, and the exact same results appear. It's definitely saved on Facebook servers. They are NOT deleting my searches when I ask to.

Comment: Are you sure it’s Facebook doing this and not your browser?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just things anyone in your area of the world and in your demographic might be searching for?

Comment: @RossRidge It's definitely my past searches, as it's all people I know and searched for, and variations of those names which I also searched. And also pages I searched for and are of my interest. Absolutely no doubt of that, that it's my past searches that are saved and showing to me.

Comment: @DaleM - Definitely not my browser. I use Chrome. What I did now was open Opera with VPN enabled, log into Facebook with my account, and the exact same results appear. It's definitely saved on Facebook servers. They are NOT deleting my searches when I ask to.

Comment: "Are they allowed to do that" may be an answerable question here. "Are they doing it?" is best asked of Facebook.